# One of two dates gets lost in portablerest post

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, portable-rest

I'm trying to post my model back to my mvc web api controller, and when it leaves my xamarin.forms method, my end date is there. Once I hit my breakpoint on the web api controller, the end date is the default "01/01/0001" and gives me an error. I'm not sure how to track this down and see where the problem is. I hit the breakpoint on the xamarin side and everything is correct. I go from there to the web api controller and end time is lost. My start time date is still there, I'm just losing one date and I have no idea why. I've tried Fiddler to capture whats being posted but can't see it from the xamarin.forms app. Is there another option to capture this? Am I missing something? Here are a couple screen shots showing the values right before it goes to the controller, and then at the controller:

[image]
[image]

Here is the code on each side:

```
public async void OnSaveClicked()
    {
        var url = BaseUrl + "/classapi/ClassEdit?"; //+  classToEdit.ToString();
        //var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(url) };
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        var client = new RestClient
        {
            BaseUrl = url
        };

        var request = new RestRequest("", HttpMethod.Post)
        {
            ContentType = ContentTypes.Json,
            ReturnRawString = true
        };
        request.AddParameter("class", classToEdit);


        var result = await client.ExecuteAsync<string>(request);


        classToEdit = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<m_class>(result);

        if (classToEdit != null)
            DisplayAlert("Class Edit", "Class was successfully saved.", "OK");
    }
```

Controller:

```
 [ActionName("ClassEdit")]
    public int ClassEdit(t_class mobileClass)
    {
        mobileClass.color = "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(mobileClass).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what was going on.... my date was called end_date on my MVC model and it was called end_time on my mobile model. It was going from web to mobile just fine, but trying to send it back to the API, it didn't like the name difference.